# Build apache module on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, module

I'm using Windows and need to integrated the module mod_socket_policy_server (http://socketpolicyserver.com/). Unfortunately, it is not compiled yet, only source code, and hard to build the module on Windows. Could any one using Linux compile this for me? Or give me a simple way to build this module on Windows?

Thank all

Comment: If you manage to compile it, maybe you could publish and maintain the pre-compiled Windows version for other people who needs it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the module, and, after seeing your question, have compiled (but not extensively tested) the module on Windows 7. You can download the zip file from:

http://socketpolicyserver.com/downloads/libapache2-mod-socket-policy-server_0.0.7.zip

I would appreciate any feedback with regards to stability and performance on Windows. Thank you.